# Edit imported model in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I captured a 3D-model of a room with my Lenovo Phab 2 Pro (Tango Device).

It gave me a ".obj"-file. After importing it into Unity (per drag & drop),
is it possible to edit the mesh of that model? Cutting things off for example?

I already made a more extensive description [in the Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1359111/trim-cut-off-parts-of-a-model-in-editor.html) but did not get an answer for about a few weeks... Hopefully someone can help me with that?

See the picture for an example of what I want to cut off or trim from the model I imported:
[image: cut off parts of a model]

Comment: Not really possible. Well, it is, but it's really hard. REALLY HARD. You should use blender or something to edit the mesh and import it back to unity

Comment: Since `Tango` captures a single mesh this wouldn't be possible to do in `Unity`. I suggest to open the model in `Blender` or `3dsMax` or some application that could edit `meshes` and simply delete the parts you do not want.

Comment: ok. that helps at least a little... do you have any advice why it is exactly that hard?

Comment: @hristo ok got that. i feared that it is not directly possible and that i will have to use additional software. that makes the process a little more complex. i will do some tries with that. 3dsMax is not for free right? do you have experience with blender? any advice where i can tuts on how to quickly learn such a cutting process?

Comment: @Hristo ah nevermind. found plenty after little search :D

Comment: @Pascal Both have the option to try them for free, so that's good. I suggest you watch a quick tutorial on how to modify a `Mesh` it's as simple as it gets, compare it to cutting a piece of paper. My personal preference is `3dsMax`. Good luck!

Comment: There *are* assets on the asset store that can do this, but they're expensive and in my experience aren't very good.

Answer (score 0):

This tool allows you to edit your model in Unity. You can cut parts off, Split Edges, Delete Faces, and a bunch of other tools for modelling in Unity.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/166155